# Bootstrap Contact Form with PHP. Can't get it to work

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, github, contact-form

So I have designed a contact form for my webpage so that users can email me directly from the webpage. I have the html in contact.html and the PHP code in contactForm.php if the user succesfully inputs his/hers information and the email is sent I want the user to be redirected to thanks.html. I have tried to test it out but it just wont work. Where do i put my php file? Do I have to change anything on cPanel or GoDaddy? The code is below...

[contactForm.php](http://pastebin.com/Xe2UhPZi)

[contact.html](http://pastebin.com/v0h7f1Sq)

Comment: *Where do i put my php file?* - Anywhere that'll work; like... a folder.

Comment: This, by the way `($_POST["submit"])` doesn't do anything.

Comment: currently I have it in my public_html parent folder. I removed the $_POST["submit"]. But still no luck.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a php form script I rewrote for you: http://pastebin.com/w14MSrcL

Replace your contactForm.php codes with this and you're good to go.

Keep this file in the same directory where your html file is in.

Comment: Thanks andrew I see the mistakes that you corrected. I copied the code and placed it in the same directory. However, when I press submit the browser navigates to contactForm.php but nothing happens...

Comment: Oh sorry.... I forgot to add a semi-colon.... Give me a sec.... I'll update the php codes

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new link. Copy that and you're really good to go this time.

Comment: It worked Andrew...kind of. Thanks for your help. The email comes through but none of the fields are actually filled out. They just come out blank in the email.

Comment: figured it out had to add the name attribute to my html so that the php knew where to get the info. Thanks again!